# How can I use tomorrow's date when I need to format the date for a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

For today's date, I use:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/London", "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

For tomorrow's date I've already tried these ways but none with positive result:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date()+1, "Europe/London", "yyyy-MM-dd")

Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/London", "yyyy-MM-dd")+1

Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/London", "yyyy-MM-dd").getDate()+1

Utilities.formatDate(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1), "Europe/London", "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

How should I work to collect tomorrow's date when I need to use it according to a specific timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/London", "yyyy-MM-dd")
```